# How can I "stack" a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list

How can I reshape a nested list so that all the nested items are nested in the item prior?

e.g.

```
ex1 = [1, [2, 20], [3, 30], [4]]
ex2 = [1, [2]]
ex3 = [1]
```

expected outputs would be like this:

```
ex1 = [1, [2, 20, [3, 30, [4]]]]
ex2 = [1, [2]]
ex3 = [1]
```

I guess I'm looking to do the opposite to flattening a list.

The original list structure could nest objects of any length, but these nested objects will never contain a nested object themselves.

It might also be that there are zero nested objects.

edit: mistake in my example which I have fixed (I think)

edit2: some important clarifications missed and now added

Comment: What about `[1, 2, [3, 4]]` or `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, and what about `[[1], [2]]` vs `[1, 2]`...?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the list is longer than 2, presumably it'll contain sublists we need to stack, so pop the last one and stack it.

```
def stack(L):
    """Note: Mutates L"""
    while len(L) > 2:
        last = L.pop()
        L[-1].append(last)
```

```
>>> stack(ex1)
>>> ex1
[1, [2, 20, [3, 30, [4]]]]
>>> stack(ex2)
>>> ex2
[1, [2]]
>>> stack(ex3)
>>> ex3
[1]
```

---

#### Original solution - more complicated

Iterate backwards along the list, appending each sublist to the one before it, and then removing it from the top-level list. Although, if the top-level list has less than 3 elements, it will presumably be correct already.

```
def stack(L):
    """Note: Mutates L"""
    if len(L) < 3:
        return

    prev = L[-1]  # For use in loop
    for sublist in L[-2:0:-1]:  # Backwards from second-last to second
        sublist.append(prev)
        del L[-1]
        prev = sublist  # For next iteration
```